# Hibernate Inner join instead left outter

Tags: hibernate, hql, inner-join

I have a task to transform left outer joins to inner joins. I worked with hibernate.
I have entities:

```
@Entity
@Table("entity1")
public Entity1{
 @Id
 private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 private Entity2 field;
}

@Entity
@Table("entity2")
public class Entity2{

 @Id
 private String name;

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinTable(name = "entity3_entity2",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="entity2_name")
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "entity3_name"))
 private Entity3 field;
}

@Entity
@Table("entity3")
public class Entity3{

 @Id
 private String name;

 @OneToMany
 private Set<Entity2> field;
}
```

And I have hql:

```
SELECT e1 FROM Entity1 e1 inner join fetch e1.field e2 inner join fetch e2.field where e1.id = ?1
```

Result SQL is:

```
select ... from entity1 inner join entity2 on ... left outer join entity3_entity2 on ...
```

But i need to fetch entity3 records with inner join without any sql queries. Is any way to do it?

Comment: Hey Alexey, are you getting duplicate rows in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the records using inner join in hibernate the following query can be used.

```
<query name="findEntities">
    <query-param name="id" type="long" /> //pass id to here
    SELECT e1 FROM Entity1 e1
        inner join fetch e1.field e2 
        inner join fetch e2.field e3
    where e1 = :id
</query>
```

Or

```
@Query("SELECT e1 FROM Entity1 e1 inner join fetch e1.field e2 inner join fetch e2.field e3 where e1 = ?1")
```

Comment: I have already tried this query. But result sql was: select ... from entity1 inner join entity2 on ... left outer join entity3_entity2 on ... inner join entity3 on ....